# Sort map with velocity

Tags: sorting, dictionary, velocity

I populated a map from a xml document in velocity successfully.

Now I am trying to soft the map.

Any one have an idea how to do this.

Here is my velocity template

```
#set ($root = $context.root)
#set ($nodes = $root.selectNodes("MedicalHIstoryResponse/MedicalResponses"))
#set ($container = {})

#foreach( $node in $nodes )
  #set($recordId = $!node.selectSingleNode("recordId/text()").getStringValue())
  #set($myHashMap = {
    "eventDate": $!node.selectSingleNode("EventDate/text()").getStringValue(),
    "eventType": $!node.selectSingleNode("EventType/text()").getStringValue(),
    "description": $!node.selectSingleNode("Description/text()").getStringValue(),
    "recordId": $recordId,
    "parentRecordId": $!node.selectSingleNode("parentRecordId/text()").getStringValue(),
    "noofAttachment": $!node.selectSingleNode("noofAttachment/text()").getStringValue(),
    "noofLinkFolder": $!node.selectSingleNode("noofLinkFolder/text()").getStringValue(),
    "hide": $!node.selectSingleNode("hide/text()").getStringValue(),
    "addedBy": $!node.selectSingleNode("addedBy/text()").getStringValue()
  })
  #set ($discard = $container.put($recordId, $myHashMap))
#end

#foreach($obj in $container)
  $obj
#end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TreeMap instead of an HashMap. It will keep entries sorted by key.

You will need a small tool to create empty maps in VTL (or you can use the definitely ugly hack:

```
#set($dummy="")
#set($container = $dummy.class.forName("java.util.TreeMap").newInstance())
```

at least for testing purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: use Velocity Sort Tool - docs [here](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html).

```
#foreach($obj in $sorter.sort($container))
  $obj
#end
```

You'll need to add the sort tool to the Velocity context using

```
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext(variableMap);
// now add in the velocity tools required
velocityContext.put("sorter", new SortTool());
```

Better solution: follow MVC principles and do all this work in Java code.  Amongst other benefits, this would give you the flexibility to apply a custom sort order (Comparator).  See my other SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31249622/993262) for a full explanation and justification.